# Overwrite disk space for the purpose of deleting old data

Tags: beginner, c, file

I have written a little program that overwrites memory. It creates useless files in a folder named "folder" (I am so creative). The purpose is to overwrite old data. It's not a very professional program because I am a beginner, but I think it should do for which it is destined: exhaust memory and thus maybe overwrite old data that was stored on it. If you have tips for me how to imrove this program or how to make it faster in it's execution I would be thankful!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int create_files(int number_of_files, int number_of_values);

int main()
{
    int number_of_files;
    int number_of_values;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("before using this program create a folder with the name \"folder\"\nin the same folder this program is located\n");
    printf("number of files: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_files);
    printf("number of values: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_values);

    create_files(number_of_files, number_of_values);

}

void create_files(int number_of_files, int number_of_values)
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_files; i++)
    {
        FILE * file;
        char file_name[30] = "./folder/";
        char file_number[20];
        sprintf(file_number, "%d", i);
        strcat(file_name, file_number);
        file = fopen(file_name, "w+");

        for(int j = 0; j < number_of_values; j++)
        {
            int random_value = rand();
            fprintf(file, "%d", random_value);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hrmm... Why are you using `char` for file_name and file_number? Shouldn't they be `string` and `int` respectively?

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't work how you think with SSDs, and will likely shorten their lifetime needlessly.

Comment: @Sometowngeek C does not have a `string`. You work with `char *` or `char [N]`.

Comment: In C a string is not a default data type. There is also no composed data type defined in a standard library of C. But with knowledge string handling in C is also not a witchcraft.

Comment: Oop. I learned something new.

Comment: @DexterThorn Please do not update your question according to the answers! Code Review works by providing suggestions how to improve the original code. Please edit your question to contain the original code, and open a new question if you want further suggestions based on the changes. If you do open a new question based on this one, link to the new one from here, and to this one from the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a habit of initializing variables. Your `scanf`might fail:

```
scanf("%d", &number_of_files);
```

What happens if I answer `"many"`? Well, first of all, [`scanf` will return `0`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and next `number_of_files` won't get changed. So its value is unknown. If we use it, we end up with undefined behaviour, which is a fancy term to say "we have no idea what will happen".

So in order to at least prevent something like `number_of_files = 1000000000` and `number_of_values = 10000000` just because the input failed, make sure to initialize your values and maybe check whether `scanf` succeeded:

```
int main()
{
    int number_of_files  = 0;
    int number_of_values = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("before using this program create a folder with the name \"folder\"\nin the same folder this program is located\n");
    printf("number of files: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &number_of_files) != 1) {
       // handle the error?
    }
    printf("number of values: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &number_of_values) != 1) {
       // handle the error?
    }

    create_files(number_of_files, number_of_values);
}
```

Note that your usage is misleading: the folder has to be located in the folder the program is *run*, not *located*.

## Let the compiler help you

Note that I got rid of the `int i`? You declared it, but you've never used it. You probably had all of your program in your `main` and decided to refactor (good!), but you forgot not only the `i`, but to `return` something in `create_files`. Both of these mishaps could have been found with compiler flags:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic main.c

main.c: In function 'int main()':    
main.c:10:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]    
     int i;    
         ^    
main.c: In function 'int create_files(int, int)':    
main.c:44:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }    
 ^
```

## Initialize the seed once

I've moved the `srand` call into `main`. That way there will be only one call to `srand`, regardless of how many times you call `create_files`. That's handy since

- we can now reconstruct the flow if we print the seed
- we can reconstruct the flow even if we call `create_files` multiple times
- we don't have to worry about calling `create_files` twice in the same second

## Simplify and continue to check errors

You can use `sprintf` to print your `file_name` directly:

```
char file_name[50] = "";
sprintf(file_name, "./folder/trash-%015d");
```

This will format `file_name` as `"./folder/trash-000000000000001"`. Since every file name has the same length, the sorting is somewhat better, and the `trash-` prefix will simplify the users life in case they accidentally had a folder called `folder` (but they should really rename that folder).

That being said, you should check whether you were able to open that file at all, and whether you could actually write to it. Remember, you're trying to fill a disk (not memory) to the brim. If it's full, you cannot continue to write, and either `fopen` or `fprintf` will fail:

```
if(!(file = fopen(file_name, "w+")))
{
    perror("Could not open file");
    return i;
}

for(int j = 0; j < number_of_values; j++)
{
    int random_value = rand();
    if(fprintf(file, "%d", random_value) < 0)
    {
        fclose(file);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Note that I return `i` because I think you've wanted to return the number of created files, but I'm not sure. If you didn't want to return anything at all, change `create_files` return type to `void`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips! Yes, i first wanted to write it all in the main function, but then it looked a little bit unordered und so have written a second function and forgot to delete the variable i. The function should be of type "void", i will correct this.

Comment: @DexterThorn As already mentioned in a comment on the question, please do not correct the code in the question. The original code should not be updated. Optionally you can open a new question and link between them.